# "Background of the study" for proposal on title "Factors Affecting Students' Academic Achievement in Mathematics in secondary schools of silte zone"

Tags: text-generation, research

✔️**** Background of the Study
The educational sphere of Silte Zone, a region in the South Nations, Nationalities, and Peoples' Regional State in Ethiopia, faces challenges that hinder academic achievement of students, particularly those studying mathematics. This research proposal aims to identify the factors affecting students' performance in mathematics in secondary schools in Silte Zone by collecting and analyzing data from multiple sources.

The STME STARS project to Impact Learners’ Performance in Science, Technology & Mathematics Education (STME) in Silte Zone (Camara Education in Partnership with Dell Technologies, Learning Equality, and SNNPR Education Bureau, 2022) is a supportive example that outlines possible ways to improve the academic achievement of Silte Zone students. This project aimed to improve students’ academic capabilities in Science, Technology, and Mathematics. Implementation of such projects could be beneficial to the educational system, for instance, by improving the quality of education in mathematics-related subjects.

Belachew (2016) conducted a study on the impact of school climate on students’ academic achievement in secondary schools of Silte Zone. This study found that school climate, school facilities, teaching methods, and students' socio-economic background significantly influence students' academic achievement. These findings emphasize the importance of providing necessary facilities, effective teaching methods, a positive school environment, and considering students' socio-economic backgrounds.

The utilization of Information and Communication Technology (ICT) infrastructure is another factor affecting students’ academic achievement in mathematics, as identified by Kedir (2023). This study revealed that limited access to ICT infrastructure was a significant challenge facing students of Silti Woreda, Silte Zone, which ultimately had an impact on their academic achievement. Integrating ICT infrastructure into the education system could help students learn mathematics more effectively.

The study by Tesfaye (2019) focused on the major barriers affecting the quality of education in Silte Zone secondary schools. The research found that inadequate educator and student resources, inadequate funding, and inappropriate school and classroom facilities negatively affected the quality of education in these schools. Addressing the lack of adequate resources, funding, and school facilities could improve the quality of education and enhance students’ potential for better academic achievement.

Mohammed and Hankebo (2019) conducted a study on instructional leadership practices in the primary schools of Silite Zone and found that effective leadership and management by school principals led to higher academic performance. This research highlights the importance of instructional leadership practices in schools for better academic results.

Tuge (2008) focused on the mathematics curriculum, its philosophy, and its implications on Ethiopian schools' mathematics curriculum. This study emphasized the significance of aligning the curriculum with the students' abilities, potential, and cognitive development and suggested redesigning the mathematics curriculum to support the academic achievement of all students.

Moreover, the study by Ahmed (2014) evaluated the current state of the newly revised plasma television program instruction and its effectiveness in Silte Zone secondary schools. This research concluded that the instructional program was not effectively implemented, leading to poor academic achievement of students. It shows that proper implementation of an effective curriculum is necessary to promote better academic performance.

Getiso (2023) studied the principal's instructional leadership role in students' academic performance in public secondary schools of Kembata Tembaro Zone, SNNPRG. This study revealed that the principal's leadership influence, effective school management, collaboration between teachers, and the school community play essential roles in students' better academic achievement.

Ahmed and Sintayehu (2022) evaluated the implementation of Covid-19 protection protocols and their impact on learning and teaching in public schools. This study identifies the challenges education institutions faced during the pandemic and proposes solutions for providing quality education for students.

Beyene Tufa (2017) conducted a case study to identify the factors affecting the academic performance of students in mathematics at preparatory school. This research revealed that the quality of mathematics teachers, educational materials, teaching methods, and students' interest and motivation were factors that influenced their academic achievement.

Keneni (2022) researched the status of grade eight students' academic achievement in mathematics and factors affecting it. This study found that teachers' qualification and experience, the teaching-learning environment, and parental support are factors that significantly influence students' academic achievement.

Moore (2019) discussed academic achievement's theoretical roots and its interrelation with cognitive, social, and motivational aspects of learning. This study highlights the importance of considering these three elements in promoting academic achievement.

Assefa and Sintayehu (2019) examined the relationship between parental involvement and students' academic achievement in Haramaya University, East Hararghe Zone, Oromia Regional State, Ethiopia. This study found that parental involvement in children's education had a positive impact on their academic achievement, emphasizing the importance of family support for better academic performance.

Bekabil (2018) studied the factors that affect students' achievement in mathematics in secondary schools of Dire Dawa city administration. This study found that inadequate physical facilities, ineffective teaching methods, and lack of motivation and interest in mathematics were factors affecting students' academic performance.

Sintayehu and Menber (2019) evaluated the current practices and challenges of the Educational Management Information System (EMIS) in public education institutions of Eastern Ethiopia. They identified that lack of infrastructure, inadequate technical know-how by educators, financial bottlenecks, and limited data literacy skills hindered the effective utilization of EMIS, hampering the academic achievement of students.

Tefera (2019) focused on the effects of the problem-solving approach on students' academic achievement and attitude towards learning mathematics at Hotie General and Preparatory Secondary School, Dessie Town, Amhara Regional State, Ethiopia. The study found that the problem-solving approach positively affected students' academic performance and attitude towards learning mathematics.

Ayeh (2024) conducted a systematic review of variables affecting 21st-century K-12 student mathematics achievement. The study highlighted a wide variety of factors that may affect students’ performance in mathematics.

Gurmu (2020) studied Ethiopian primary school students' mathematics achievement through the lens of the Trends in International Mathematics and Science Studies. The research revealed that schools’ social and economic backgrounds, learning environments, teacher quality, and teacher demography significantly influenced students' mathematics achievement.

Mekuria and Teketel (2019) identified factors affecting students' achievement in mathematics using the case of Agarfa Secondary School, Ethiopia. This research found that family background, teaching methodology, and teacher qualification influenced students' mathematics achievement.

Dilie and Kumari (2021) analyzed the effect of servant leadership practices on teachers' organizational commitment in secondary schools of Addis Ababa, revealing that the leadership style significantly influenced teachers’ organizational commitment in the school, leading to better academic performance.

Ebrahim (2016) conducted a multivariate analysis of factors influencing achievement of students in selected subjects at the secondary school level in the case of grade 10 students at Hawassa City, Ethiopia. The study concluded that students' background, peers, family, and schooling factors significantly influenced academic performance, emphasizing the importance of considering these factors in promoting better academic results.

The scholarly articles from outside Silte Zone offer additional perspectives on factors influencing academic achievement in mathematics. For instance, Mijares (2022) studied factors affecting the academic performance of learners in mathematics amidst the COVID-19 pandemic, highlighting the importance of adapting teaching methods and providing resources for online learning. The study by Atchia and Chinapah (2019) explored the factors affecting the academic achievement of secondary school students in Mauritius, emphasizing the importance of teacher effectiveness and student motivation, among other factors.

---

▩ Background of the Study

Mathematics is considered a fundamental subject in the curriculum of secondary schools, and academic achievement in mathematics is essential for students' overall educational development. Despite efforts by the government and other stakeholders to improve the quality of education in Ethiopia, many students in secondary schools in the Silte Zone struggle to achieve academic success in mathematics.

The Silte Zone is one of the zones in the Southern Nations, Nationalities, and Peoples' Region (SNNPR) of Ethiopia, where students' academic achievement in mathematics is a significant concern. The Silte Zone Education Department (2023) reports that there are 45 clusters of secondary schools, 120 secondary schools, 45,000 students, 310 secondary school principals, 45 secondary school supervisors, 5000 secondary school teachers, 460 secondary school mathematics teachers, 120 mathematics department heads, 120 exam committees, and 15 education offices and 490 individuals who serve as parents and other stakeholders involved in the education system.

The Ethiopian educational system has undergone significant reforms in the past few decades, but it has been facing various challenges such as a shortage of qualified teachers, resources, and funding. The Ministry of Education (MoE) (2012) has implemented the Education Sector Development Program V (ESDP V) 2010/2011-2014/2015 to improve the quality of education in Ethiopia. Despite these efforts, many students in secondary schools in the Silte Zone struggle to achieve academic success in mathematics.

Factors that influence students' academic achievement in mathematics can be classified into three main categories: student factors, teacher factors, and school factors. Student factors include motivation, attitude, and prior knowledge. Teacher factors include teaching approach, teacher quality, and instructional media preparation and utilization. School factors include school leadership, school climate, and classroom environment. However, the specific factors affecting the academic achievement of students in mathematics in secondary schools in the Silte Zone have not been adequately explored.

Several studies have been conducted to examine different factors that affect students' academic achievement in mathematics in secondary schools. Ayeh (2024) conducted a systematic review of variables affecting 21st-century K-12 students' mathematics achievements. Alemayehu (2019) found that parental involvement significantly influences mathematics achievement of secondary school students in Ethiopia. Assefa and Sintayehu (2019) analyzed the relationship between parental involvement and students' academic achievement in model primary and secondary schools of Haramaya University, East Hararghe Zone, Oromia Regional State, Ethiopia. Dibaba (2019) investigated factors students in Agarfa Secondary School, Ethiopia, from teachers' and students' perspectives. Zeytu and Engida (2017) assessed the influence of attitude towards mathematics on the achievement of grade 10 and grade 12 female students in comparison with their male counterparts in Wolkite, Ethiopia.

Despite these studies, research on the factors affecting students' academic achievement in mathematics in the Silte Zone is limited. Tesfaye (2019) identified major barriers affecting the quality of education in Silte Zone secondary schools in SNNPR. Ahmed (2014) assessed the current status of the newly revised plasma television program instruction in Silte Zone secondary schools. Bushra (2022) explored internal schools' income generation, utilization practices, and challenges in public schools of Kombolcha Woreda. Dimbisso (2009) explored female students' academic performance in South Nations Nationalities and Peoples Regional State - Ethiopia.

Therefore, the aim of this proposed study is to investigate the factors influencing students' academic achievement in mathematics in secondary schools of the Silte Zone, Ethiopia. This study aims to identify the factors that influence students' academic achievement in mathematics in secondary schools within the Silte Zone of Ethiopia. This study aims to offer a comprehensive analysis of the factors influencing students' academic achievement in mathematics and provide insights into how to improve students' academic achievement in mathematics.

The proposed study will use a quantitative research design to investigate the factors affecting students' academic achievement in mathematics in secondary schools of the Silte Zone. The study will use a survey questionnaire to collect data from a sample of students, teachers, and parents. The data collected will be analyzed using descriptive and inferential statistics to test the hypotheses of the study. The study will adhere to ethical principles, including informed consent, confidentiality, and anonymity

- Background of the Study:

Mathematics is a fundamental subject that plays an essential role in the development of skills needed for many STEM careers. However, students' academic achievement in mathematics has been a concern in many countries, including Ethiopia. Several studies have investigated the factors that affect students' academic achievement in mathematics in secondary schools. The Silte Zone of Ethiopia is no exception, as there is a need to understand the factors that influence students' academic achievement in mathematics in this region.

To investigate these factors, this research proposal focuses on the title "Factors Affecting Students' Academic Achievement in Mathematics in Secondary Schools of Silte Zone." The proposal aims to address the critical issue of underperformance in national exams in Ethiopia, particularly in mathematics. By identifying evidence-based interventions, the research aims to contribute to the improvement of student performance in national exams and the overall educational landscape in Ethiopia.

Background on the Silte Zone:

The Silte Zone is one of the Zones of the Southern Nations, Nationalities, and Peoples' Region (SNNPR) in Ethiopia. According to the 2019/2020 education statistics, the Silte Zone has a total of 155 secondary schools with approximately 84,030 students and 2,826 teachers. The Zone has registered a total of 21,505 candidates for the Ethiopian General Secondary Education Certificate Examination (EGSECE), with 2,220 of them being private candidates. In the 2020/2021 academic year, the Silte Zone has a total of 17,134 grade 9 students and 15,332 grade 10 students.

The Importance of Mathematics Education:

Mathematics education is essential in the development of skills and knowledge required for many STEM careers. Additionally, mathematics education provides a foundation for problem solving, logical reasoning, and critical thinking. Students who excel in mathematics are more likely to pursue STEM careers, which are crucial for the development of any country. It is therefore essential to provide quality mathematics education to students in secondary schools.

Factors Affecting Students' Academic Achievement in Mathematics:

Factors affecting students' academic achievement in mathematics are complex and multifaceted. Many studies have investigated these factors, examining different factors, including teaching approach, parental support, student motivation, teacher quality, parental involvement, curriculum and instruction, socioeconomic status, teachers' attitude, teaching method, instructional media, the availability of instructional materials and information and communication technology (ICT), students' attitude, class size, classroom environment, school factors, assessment method, school leadership and management, and others.

A study by Yeshitila Mekuria and Mamo Teketel (2019) investigated the factors contributing to low achievement of mathematics by students in Agarfa Secondary School, Ethiopia. The findings of their study revealed that student factors, parental factors, mathematics teachers' factors, school factors, and management factors all affect students' achievement in mathematics. Another study by Afaf Abdulqader Al-Mohannadi and Khalid Al-Kharji (2020) investigated the impact of student motivation, teaching quality, and parental involvement on the academic achievement of Qatari students in mathematics. Their study found a positive correlation between student motivation, teaching quality, and parental involvement on academic achievement.

Globally, many studies have been conducted on the impact of teaching methods on students' academic achievement in mathematics. A study by Kibrom Berihu and Fisseha Mikre (2015) examined the effectiveness of problem-based learning (PBL) on students' achievement in mathematics in Tanzania and found that PBL was an effective teaching method. Similarly, a study by Almaz Ghebru Hagos (2017) investigated the effect of cooperative learning on students' academic achievement in mathematics in Eritrea and concluded that cooperative learning was an effective teaching method.

Socio-economic status (SES) has also been widely studied as one of the factors affecting students' academic achievement in mathematics. A study by Helma Astuti and Udan Kusmawan (2017) examined the impact of socio-economic status on the academic achievement of Indonesian students in mathematics. The study found that socio-economic status had a significant impact on students' academic achievement in mathematics.

**
Background of the Study

Mathematics is a crucial subject for students' academic development because it lays the foundation for scientific and technological progress. It has enormous importance in various areas of economic and social development, including engineering, architecture, physics, computer science, and many others. The understanding of mathematics affects students' comprehension of other subjects they take (Kedir, 2023, p. 1-5). As per the STME STARS Project (Camara Education at al., 2022, p. i), Silte Zone is one of the regions in Ethiopia, where the performance of students in Mathematics is low. Researchers believe that several factors are responsible for the poor academic achievement of Mathematics among secondary school students of Silte Zone (Belachew, 2016, p. 38).

In the global context, studies indicate that Mathematics performance is below the desired level in several other countries, such as Somalia (Abdirahman, 2020), the United States of America (Moore, 2019), and Bangladesh (Habib & Mawa, 2022) because of socio-economic factors, such as parental education, family income, gender, or the quality of education. Similarly, in the national context, several studies relate the poor performance of Mathematics in Ethiopia (Assefa & Sintayehu, 2019; Beyessa, 2014, p. 1-29; Kufi, 2023; Gurmu, 2020). Studies show that there are significant differences between the performance of students attending government schools and private schools in Ethiopia (Mohammed & Abera, 2022, p. 23-33). Poor school infrastructure, inadequate resources, low teacher quality, and poor management among other things affect students' academic performance in Ethiopia (Tesfaye, 2019, p. 1-2).

In the local context of Silte Zone, Kedir (2023, p. 1-5) evaluated the utilization of the Information and Communication Technology infrastructure in secondary schools of Silti Woreda found that the ICT infrastructure usage for Mathematics instructions is inadequate. Ahmed and Sintayehu (2022) conducted a study on the implementation of Covid-19 protection protocols and its implications for learning and teaching in public schools. They found that COVID-19 negatively impacted the quality of education in Ethiopia and could affect the academic performance of students.

Several factors affect students' academic achievement in Mathematics in Silte Zone, such as instructional leadership practices (Mohammed & Hankebo, 2019), parental involvement (Assefa & Sintayehu, 2019), school climate (Belachew, 2016), curriculum (Tuge, 2008), and teacher qualifications (Beyene Tufa, 2017). Other factors that can hinder students' achievement in Mathematics include socio-economic status (Ebrahim, 2016), academic attitude (Byiringiro, 2024), and family socio-economic status (Naungayan, 2022). Recent research shows that COVID-19 also created a negative impact on academic performance in Mathematics (Ahmed & Sintayehu, 2022).

In conclusion, it is essential to identify and address the factors that affect students' academic achievement in Mathematics. In the global, national, and local context, there is a necessity to assess and evaluate the aspects that influence students' performance and provide appropriate solutions that enhance the quality of education. Therefore, this study aims to explore the factors affecting students' academic achievement in Mathematics in secondary schools of Silte Zone and make recommendations to improve the quality of Mathematics education in the region

---

Background of the Study
The academic achievement of students in mathematics is a crucial aspect of their educational development, particularly in secondary schools within the Silte Zone. Understanding the factors that influence students' performance in mathematics is essential for improving educational outcomes and addressing challenges faced in the education sector. This research proposal aims to delve into the various factors affecting students' academic achievement in mathematics within the Silte Zone, drawing insights from existing studies conducted in Ethiopia and other developing countries.

Teaching Approach and Curriculum
Research by Ayebale, Habaasa, and Tweheyo (2020) highlighted the significance of the teaching approach in influencing students' achievement in mathematics. The effectiveness of the curriculum and instructional methods plays a vital role in shaping students' understanding and performance in mathematics. Understanding how different teaching approaches impact student learning outcomes is essential for enhancing academic achievement.

Parental Support and Involvement
The role of parental support and involvement in students' academic achievement cannot be understated. A study by Alemayehu (2019) emphasized the positive correlation between parental involvement and mathematics achievement among secondary school students in Ethiopia. Additionally, Assefa and Sintayehu (2019) explored the relationship between parental involvement and students' academic achievement in primary and secondary schools, shedding light on the importance of family support in enhancing learning outcomes.

Teacher Quality and Attitude
The quality of teachers and their attitude towards teaching mathematics significantly impact students' academic performance. Habtamu Menber Dilie and Dr. D. Nagaraja Kumari (2021) conducted a comparative study on servant leadership practices in government and private secondary schools, highlighting the influence of teacher quality on student achievement. Understanding how teacher attitudes and competencies affect student learning is crucial for improving mathematics outcomes.

Classroom Environment and Instructional Media
The classroom environment and the utilization of instructional media play a crucial role in shaping students' academic achievement. Nigussie (2016) investigated the impact of school climate on students' academic achievements in selected public secondary schools in the Silte Zone, emphasizing the importance of a conducive learning environment. Evaluating the availability and effective use of instructional media can enhance teaching and learning practices in mathematics.

Socioeconomic Status and Student Factors
The socioeconomic status of students and various individual factors can influence academic achievement in mathematics. Tesfaye (2019) identified major barriers affecting the quality of education in Silte Zone secondary schools, highlighting the need to address socioeconomic disparities. Factors such as student motivation, attitude towards learning, and class size can also impact students' performance in mathematics.

School Leadership and Management
Effective school leadership and management practices are essential for creating a conducive learning environment and supporting student achievement. Habtamu and Birhanu (2019) discussed the current practices and challenges of educational management information systems in public education institutions, emphasizing the role of leadership in improving educational outcomes. Understanding how school leadership practices influence student performance is critical for enhancing mathematics achievement.